# Ubuntu shell - export to file only executables

Tags: 16.04, command-line

I am trying to export to a file the size of only the executable files in my directory (which doesn't ends with `.sh`).

This is the command I made, which, it seems, export non-executable as well as executable files:

```
file -x -type  | size * > /home/user/Desktop/userbinfiles.xls
```

What I want to achieve, if it's possible, is that kind of file exported:

A file with:

1. size of the file
2. type of the file
3. file name

I understand my command doesn't do that.

And Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command to execute `size` on all execute-ables files:

```
find . -executable -type f | xargs size
```

- The `find` command will find all execute-ables files under the current directory
- `xargs` will send the result list of files to be processed by the `size` command

You can use the following command to execute `size` on all execute-ables files which doesn't ends with `.sh`:

```
find . -executable -type f  | grep -v '\.sh$' |  xargs size
```

- The command `grep -v '\.sh$'`  will remove all files ends with `.sh` from the list

Comment: is there a way to filter out the script files?

Comment: How do you identify a script file? (e.g. does it ends with `.sh`, etc) ?

Comment: yes, supposed we do identify a file like that

Comment: @Alan - I've updated my answer to remove files ends with `.sh`